# Ruby on Rails - is many-to-many relation needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

Im quite new to Ruby on Rails, I've only completed Michael Hart [railstutorial.org](http://railstutorial.org) and now with tutorial as a base of my new project I'm working on simple electronic prescription service.
What I feel very confused about is many-to-many relations in RoR and it would be nice to avoid them but I am not sure if thats possible with functionality that I need.

Here is my basic EER with relations table that is going to connect prescription with medicines that it should include.

[image]

I would much appreciate any ideas about how to simplify this one, or maybe it's not really that hard to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't avoid the `many-to-many` association, it's only about working with a join model

You can just use [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

[image]

You'd just need to do this:

```
#app/models/prescription.rb
Class Prescription < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relations
    has_many :medicines, through: :relations
end

#app/models/relation.rb
Class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :prescription
    belongs_to :medicine
end

#app/models/medicine.rb
Class Medicine < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :relations
    has_many :prescriptions, through: :relations
end
```

Comment: And with the rest its just normal like class medicine also belongs_to patient and belongs_to user yes? Thanks for answer anyway as soon as I implement this into my model I will let you know how it works for me.

Comment: Hey @Rich i was thinking if you can help me with another issue (same app) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461902/rails4-autocomplete-form-with-multiple-inputs-html-data-id-element-overwritten